# Matrix addition and definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Is strict/weak negative/positive definiteness/semidefiniteness of matrices preserved under matrix addition?

I tried to do this for 2x2 matrix but even this wasn't easy. (I tried to use the principal minors definition of definiteness)

Comment: Note that $x^T (A+B)x=(x^TAx)+(x^TBx)$ and think about what happens when you add two quadratic forms (which are just polynomials).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obvious if you use the definition that a matrix $A$ is positive definite if $x^TAx>0$ for all $x\ne 0$. Then we have $x^T(A+B)x=x^TAx+x^TBx>0$. The other kinds of definiteness are similar.